# The control is not entering the getJSON() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, getjson

**working** on side project using openweathermap api...
**i** am using my own api key, the one mentioned here is generic and works for someone who doesnt have an account, it's free anyways...
**Also** i am using bootstrap toggle lib...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Weather Now</Title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">Local Weather</h1>
  <input id="tog" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="large" data-on="&#8451;" data-off="&#8457;" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="success">
  <ul>
    <li id="city"></li>
    <li id="weatherType"></li>
    <li id="temp"></li>
    <li id="windSpeed"></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  var long,lat,weatherType,temp,kelvin,celsius,fahrenheit,city,apiObj;

  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      long = position.coords.longitude;console.log(long);
      lat = position.coords.latitude;console.log(lat);

      apiObj = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1";
      console.log(apiObj);

      $.getJSON(apiObj,function(data){
        console.log("hi");
        weatherType = data.weather[0].description;console.log(weatherType);
        kelvin = data.main.temp;console.log(kelvin);
        fahrenheit = (kelvin)*(9/5)-459.67;console.log(fahrenheit);
        celsius = kelvin-273;console.log(celsius);
        city = data.city;console.log(city);

        if($('#tog').prop('checked')){
            $('#temp').html('hi '+celsius); //doesnt work
          }
        else{
            $('#temp').html(fahrenheit);
          }

        });
        console.log("bye");

      });

    }
  });
```

**Example JSON:**

*http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1*

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":139.01,
      "lat":35.02
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":285.514,
      "pressure":1013.75,
      "humidity":100,
      "temp_min":285.514,
      "temp_max":285.514,
      "sea_level":1023.22,
      "grnd_level":1013.75
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":5.52,
      "deg":311
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":0
   },
   "dt":1485792967,
   "sys":{
      "message":0.0025,
      "country":"JP",
      "sunrise":1485726240,
      "sunset":1485763863
   },
   "id":1907296,
   "name":"Tawarano",
   "cod":200
}
```

**Console Output:**
Outputs Long, Lat, api-url and bye...nothing in between(the code in getJSON)...
***What's happening?***

**UPDATE:**

So as mentioned by the ppl here i checked stuff and it was throwing an error...the error was "***Blocked loading mixed active content***”

**What is Mixed Content?**(*refered from stackoverflow answer*)
When a user visits a page served over HTTP, their connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and MITM attacks.

However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served over HTTPS. When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over HTTP. The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS pages.

**The** API call provided by 'openweathermap' is 'http', in my case since it is a side project i hard coded/added 's' making it 'https' and it worked!

**If** you are writing professional code i suggest ask API vendor for https/secure connection! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you paste an example JSON (since it requires an access/API key, we do not have access to the endpoint) returned by the service?

Comment: Check the network tab of developer tools, see if that getJSON request is being sent, and a correct-looking response received

Answer (score 1):

The thing between "api-url" and "bye" is the [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) call. That function in there is the success-callback. That fact that it does not get executed, means that the `getJSON()` must not have completed successfully.

To figure out why, you should debug that request.

- Does that URL give a response at all?
- Is it a success-response (status code 2xx)?
- Does it return JSON?

If none of those help you, you could convert the `getJSON`-call to a `$.ajax`-call and add an error-callback. That should *certainly* get called. See what kind of error it gets.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: apiObj,
  success: function (data) { /* your function body */ }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  console.error(jqXHR.responseJSON);
});
```

Update: I am getting **401 Unauthorized** as a response.

```
{
  "cod": 401,
  "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."
}
```

Comment: It does return JSON... when i copy-pasted the o/p from console.log(apiObj) in the browser...